# Dynamic Subfolders created in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: dynamic, structure, google-cloud-storage, directory

1) I want a dynamic folder and sub-folders structure to be created in Google cloud storage through gsutil or python. Whenever a user creates a job_id in a web portal, it should create the below folder structure.
For example, 
**$BUCKET/CV/$JOB_ID 
$BUCKET/JD/$JOB_ID
$BUCKET/Report/$JOB_ID
2) Can i use these dynamic file paths in a python NLP script to process the algorithm.

Comment: What have you tried so far in your code? You can of course create subfolders, but bear in mind first that folders in GCS [are objects that happens to have a / in the end](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork).

Comment: from google.cloud import storage
def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
  """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
  storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob("folderName/" + destination_blob_name)
blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
    source_file_name,
    destination_blob_name))

Comment: How ever i want this "folderName/" to be dynamic where i can pass the value as a query parameter from an API.

Comment: Then, modify the string "folderName/" in the `bucket.blob` method, to change it to what you need from this API that you mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code that you have, base, you can do something like this:

```
from google.cloud import storage 
def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name, api_parameter): 
"""Uploads a file to the bucket.""" 
    storage_client = storage.Client() 
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name) 
    blob = bucket.blob("{}/".format(api_parameter) + destination_blob_name)
```

where `api_parameter` is the query parameter from an API that you mentioned.